# WooCommerce - Product Add-ons (Extension) not effecting price in cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, add-on, woothemes

I am running the WooCommerce extension "Product Add-ons".

I have created a catering website and ideally, the customer should be able to click the "Platinum Upgrade: Add a fresh fruit cup and a chocolate dipped strawberry to each box" to add $2.00 to the item's price.

http://tkainteractive.com/sandbox/product/angus-roast-beef-avocado/

On the product page, when you click that checkbox, the price LOOKS like it changes, but when you go to look at that item in your cart, it DOES NOT have the increased price for the add-on.

I have tried submitting a support ticket to WooThemes (where the extension was purchased), but it's been ignored...

I am not skilled outside of html5/css3 and I have no idea where to even begin to fix this.  Any direction would be MUCH appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You should test with all other plugins disabled (aside from WooCommerce and Product Addons). And you should test against a default theme. 75% of these kinds of issues are theme related. That's what Woo will ask you to do when they get to your ticket so already providing the information will move things along. I know it can be a pain to do this testing, but as a developer .. isolating the problem is so critical. Though if the problem is your theme you'll be directed to contact the theme author. Without that the problem is simply too broad.

Comment: Will putting the default theme on erase all of the customization i've done to the current theme?  I haven't touched the backend on the theme, just changed colors, margins, padding, etc.  Superficial changes.  If i switch temporarily to the default theme, will that undo all of my work on the theme?  Can I easily switch my current theme back on and maintain my changes?

Comment: If everything is saved as a theme modifcation (via the customizer) then those will be preserved when switching back. But site backups are always a good idea. The best thing to do would be to create a testing site somewhere. You could try [template debug mode](http://scottbasgaard.com/woocommerce-2-1-please-debug-template-overrides/) to test your theme's WooCommerce templates first. If that's the problem you don't need to switch your theme.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to ascertain what the problem could be but I have found in the past a good place to start is to disable AJAX in either the Theme or Woocommerce. Otherwise turn off plugins one by one and test to see if there are any conflicts also try switching themes.